# What is another way to say "sich schminken"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, synonym

When my sister `puts on make-up`, it takes her hours.

Wenn meine Schwester sich schminkt, braucht sie Stunden.

What is another way to say "sich schminken"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be many alternatives -- Some examples:

Something like getting ready for a party

> Wenn meine Schwester sich für die Party zurecht macht, braucht sie Stunden.

Or maybe to put on some color/make up

> Wenn meine Schwester Farbe/Make-up auflegt, dauert es Stunden.

Or just something like getting beautyful:

> Meine Schwerster braucht Stunden, um sich (für die Party) schick zu machen.

Comment: Besides those **fertig machen** is also used a lot.

Comment: Yepp, that's true. And I'm sure there a lot of more depending on region you are in. E.g. I'm knowing also "aufhübschen" (pretty up?)

Comment: Version 1 u. 3 beinhalten das ausprobieren von 40 Oberteilen mit 10 Röcken und 8 Hosen und trifft die Make-Up-Frage nur schlecht. Make-up auflegen oder auftragen dagegen trifft es so genau, dass die 2 anderen, schlechteren Alternativen überflüssig sind. "Sich schminken" ist auch gut, aber umfasst den Kajal-Stift, das Fingernägel lackieren und den Lippenstift. Eventuell passt auch "etwas Rouge auflegen" aber da bin ich kein Fachmann, ob das das gleiche wie Make-up ist.

Comment: `Wenn meine Schwester Farbe/Make-up auflegt, dauert es Stunden.` is only an exact equivalent to `When my sister puts on make-up, it takes her hours.`, since both of the other expressions imply also different meanings: like doing ones hair, or other body related improvements.